# Diffing two files but ignoring differences of a certain string elements

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have two files that look like this:

File1

```
IP In    IP Out    Route    Received    Sent
1.1.1.1  2.2.2.2   1.2.1.2  2314        4324

Neighbor      Prefix         Route
127.0.0.1     127.1.1.1/24   255.255.255.0
```

File2

```
IP In    IP Out    Route    Received    Sent
1.1.1.1  2.2.2.2   1.2.1.2  2432        6324

Neighbor      Prefix         Route
127.0.0.1     127.2.3.4/24   255.255.255.0
```

Running the command

```
diff -u file1.txt file2.txt
```

results in

```
--- file1.txt   2018-01-23 11:02:57.632280547 +0000
+++ file2.txt   2018-01-23 11:03:30.122293833 +0000
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 IP In    IP Out    Route    Received    Sent
-1.1.1.1  2.2.2.2   1.2.1.2  2314        4324
+1.1.1.1  2.2.2.2   1.2.1.2  2432        6324

 Neighbor      Prefix         Route
-127.0.0.1     127.1.1.1/24   255.255.255.0
+127.0.0.1     127.2.3.4/24   255.255.255.0
```

I want to output a file that lists the differences in the prefixes column only, and ignore any differences in the Received/Sent columns. I had thought of using regex

```
\w{2,4}\b
```

to capture stings between 2 and 4 characters long with the -I parameter to ignore these lines but it didn't seem to work.

So the final output I want to have is:

```
Neighbor      Prefix         Route
-127.0.0.1     127.1.1.1/24   255.255.255.0
+127.0.0.1     127.2.3.4/24   255.255.255.0
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the output you want to have finally?

Comment: @Inian edited to show desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some code that might just work... it does what you're asking for on my setup, with your example inputs, anyway.

```
diff  -I '\(\([0-9]*\.\)\{3\}[0-9]* *\)\{3\}' -U 1 f1 f2
```

Interestingly, when I used `-u` (equivalent to `-U 3`) the ignored difference shows as part of the context.

The regex is a bit unpleasant-looking because of all the escaping, but all it's doing is ignoring lines that have 3 blocks of ip addresses in a row with spaces between them.